# Convergence in distribution implies convergence in probability in proof of Delta Method

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, convergence

I'd like verification that my proof of the below claim is correct. This is part (a) of exercise 5.4.3 of Casella and Berger. I found a similar question on this forum but the response used a different argument.

> **Claim**: Let $Y_n$ be a sequence of random variables such that $\sqrt{n}(Y_n-\theta)\xrightarrow{d} N(0,\sigma^2)$. Then $Y_n\to \theta$ in probability.

Proof: Set $X_n=\sqrt{n}(Y_n-\theta)$. Note that $E(X_n)=0$. Convergence in distribution implies convergence of variances(?), so that, $\mathrm{var}(X_n)=n\cdot\mathrm{var}(Y_n)\to \sigma^2<\infty$. This forces $\mathrm{var}(Y_n)\to 0$. Now, fix $\epsilon>0$. Then \begin{align}P(|Y_n-\theta|>\epsilon) &=P(|\sqrt{n}(Y_n-\theta)|>\sqrt{n}\epsilon) \\
&=P(|X_n|>\sqrt{n}\epsilon) \\
&= P(|X_n-E(X_n)|>\sqrt{n}\epsilon)\\
&\le \frac{\mathrm{var}(X_n)}{n\epsilon^2}\quad\quad\text{(Chebyshev's Inequality)}\\
&= \frac{n\cdot\mathrm{var}(Y_n)}{n\epsilon^2}\\
&= \frac{\mathrm{var}(Y_n)}{\epsilon^2}.\end{align}

Thus, since $$0\le P(|Y_n-\theta|>\epsilon)\le\frac{\mathrm{var}(Y_n)}{\epsilon^2} \to 0,$$ the Squeeze Theorem yields $\lim_{n\to\infty}P(|Y_n-\theta|>\epsilon)=0$, i.e., $Y_n\to\theta$ in probability.

Edit: It seems that my claim regarding convergence in distribution implying convergence in variances is the problem spot. What remedies are there for this if this claim is not valid? What integrability conditions do we need?